# Maven SQL Plugin and invoking Mysql Client to generate XML file

Tags: mysql, maven

I want to create an XML file of the data that is fetched by my SQL command and I want to do that using a maven goal. Is there a way to do it. 
To be more specific, if I have to generate an XML file of the data using mysql command line client, I do this :

```
mysql --xml -e "SELECT * FROM test.person" > person-dump.xml
```

I would like to achieve the same functionality, but as a maven plugin/goal.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any plugin which will do this for you, specifically.  There is a Maven SQL plugin which will execute SQL commands (http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/), however it does not appear to have any option for dumping the data to an XML file.

It should be a relatively trivial task to write your own maven plugin (https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) taking the dbname, username, password and output file name as parameters and have it do this for you.

Comment: Sql Maven plugin does have an option to output the content to a file. What I am more interested in is how to call mysql client from within Maven plugin, because AFAIK, we can currently generate the XML from the result only using MySql client and not standard MySql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Source code of sql-maven-plugin allows you to generate results to a file; afterwards you can parse it how you want it.

```
        <id>checksql</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>checksql</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                            <groupId>ojdbc6</groupId>
                            <scope>system</scope>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <systemPath>ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar</systemPath>
                        </dependency>

                    </dependencies>

                    <configuration>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@yourDb</url>
                        <username>use</username>
                        <password>pwd</password>
                        <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>check</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                <sqlCommand>select count(*) from  your_table</sqlCommand>
                                **<outputFile>out.log</outputFile>
                                <printResultSet>true</printResultSet>**
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

This will produce an out.log with these contents:

COUNT(*)
3959

0 rows affected